# PHP - Checking for Uploaded Image

Tags: php, ajax

I'm relatively new to PHP and need some help checking to see 1. If an image has been uploaded for submission and complete one set of submission ELSE IF an image has not been uploaded, submit a different set of sql information.

I've previously tried isset(), is_uploaded_file(), and file_exists(), and cannot seem to get anything to send.

HTML FORM

```
           <form method="POST" action="php/editInv.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="editInv">
           <table>
              <tbody>
              <?php
                 $productId = $_GET['productId'];

                 require ('php/dbcon.php');

                 $con=mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);

                 $sqlId = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE productId='".$productId."'";

                 $sqlIdResult = mysqli_query($con,$sqlId);

                 while($rowId=mysqli_fetch_array($sqlIdResult)) {
              ?>
                 <tr>
                    <td>
                       <label for="productName">Product Name: </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       <input name="productName" id="productName" type="text" value="<?php echo $rowId['productName']; ?>"/>
                       <input name="prodId" id="prodId" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $rowId['productId']; ?>" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       <label for="productDesc">Product Description: </label>
                    </td>
                    <td rowspan="4">
                       <textarea name="productDesc" id="productDesc" cols="55" rows="10"><?php echo $rowId['productDesc']; ?></textarea>
                    </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>
                       <label for="gender">Gender: </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       <select name="gender" id="gender">
                          <option id="1" value="1">Male</option>
                          <option id="2" value="2">Female</option>
                          <option id="3" value="3">Unisex</option>
                       </select>
                       <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $rowId['genderId']; ?>" id="genderHid"/>
                       <script>
                          var gender=$('#genderHid').val();
                          var selected=$('#gender').find('#'+gender);
                          $(selected).attr('selected','selected');
                       </script>
                    </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>
                       <label for="inventory">Inventory: </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       <input type="number" name="inventory" id="inventory" value="<?php echo $rowId['inventory']; ?>"/>
                    </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>
                       <label for="price">Price: </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       $<input type="text" name="price" id="price" value="<?php echo $rowId['price']; ?>" />
                    </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>
                       <label for="productImage">Upload Image: </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       <input type="file" name="productImage" id="productImage" />
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="2">
                       <div id="progress" style="width:100%;">
                          <div id="bar" style="height:50px;background-color:blue;width:0%;">
                          </div>
                          <p id="percent"></p>
                       </div>
                    </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">
                       <img id="prevImage" style="" src="<?php echo $rowId['productImage']; ?>" />
                    </td>
                    <td id="response">

                    </td>
                    <td>
                       <button type="submit" id="editInv">Edit Item</button>
                    </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                 </tr>
              <?php
              };
              ?>
              </tbody>
           </table>
           </form>
```

AJAX

```
  var options = {
  beforeSubmit: function() {
     // pre submit callback
     $("#progress").show();
     $("#percent").html("0%");
  },
  data: {
     productName : $('#productName').val(),
     productDesc : $('#productDesc').val(),
     inventory : $('#inventory').val(),
     price : $('#price').val(),
     gender : $('#gender').val(),
     image : $('#prevImage').attr('src'),
     prodId : $('#prodId').val()
  },
  uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
     //during submission
     $("#bar").width(percentComplete+'%');
     $("#percent").html(percentComplete+'%');
  },
  success: function(msg) {
     //post submit call back
     $(".bar").css("width","100%");
     $(".percent").html('100%');
     $("#response").html(response.responseText);
  },
  complete: function(response) {
     if(response.responseText=="Invalid File"){
     } else {
        $("#response").html(response.responseText);
        //$("#addNew")[0].reset();
        //$("#prevImage").attr('src','').hide();
        $(".bar").css("width","0%");
        $(".percent").html('0%');
     }

  },
  error: function(response) {
     alert(response.responseText);
  }

};

$("#editInv").ajaxForm(options);
```

PHP

```
//If a file has been uploaded
if (!empty($_FILES["productImage"]["name"])) {

 $target_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/images/inventory/";
 $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["productImage"]["name"]);
 $fileName = str_replace(' ', '', $productName);
 $target_file_insert = "/images/inventory/" . $fileName . ".jpg";
 $targetFileUpload = $target_dir . $fileName . ".jpg";


 $sql1 = "UPDATE products SET productName='".$productName."', productDesc='".$productDesc."', inventory='".$inventory."', price='".$price."', genderId='".$gender."', productImage='".$targetFileUpload."' WHERE productId='".$prodId."'";

 mysqli_query($con,$sql1);

 $uploadOk = 1;
 $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
 // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
 if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
     $check = getimagesize($_FILES["productImage"]["tmp_name"]);
     if($check !== false) {
         echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
         $uploadOk = 1;
     } else {
         echo "File is not an image.";
         $uploadOk = 0;
     }
 }
 // Allow certain file formats
 if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "JPG" && $imageFileType != "JPEG") {
     echo "Sorry, only JPG, and JPEG files are allowed.";
     $uploadOk = 0;
 }
 // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
 if ($uploadOk == 0) {
     echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
 // if everything is ok, try to upload file
 } else {
     if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["productImage"]["tmp_name"], $targetFileUpload)) {
         mysqli_close($con);
     } else {
         echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
     }
 }
} else
//If a file has not been uploaded
/*if (empty($_FILES["productImage"]["name"])) */{
  $sql2="UPDATE products SET productName='".$productName."', productDesc='".$productDesc."', inventory='".$inventory."', price='".$price."', genderId='".$gender."', productImage='".$image."' WHERE productId='".$prodId."'";

  mysqli_query($con,$sql2);
}
```

Comment: At least two problems in your AJAX code: 1) you've posted an options object, but no actual call to AJAX; 2) even if you did send this, your code sends only the `src` property of the image, not the image itself so your `$_FILES` array in your PHP script will be empty.

Comment: the SRC is intended as the place holder for when there is no image upload, it will submit the SRC which is originally pulled from the database. I'm checking to see if there is a new uploaded file. If there is no new uploaded file, then $_FILES should not have anything to do with the SRC variable. 

The call to ajax is below the script, 
    
$("#editInv").ajaxForm(options);

Updated the call in the code

Comment: fyi, I wasn't trying to post all of my HTML elements here, but the $_FILES["productImage"] calls to a file-type input in the HTML while the src points to the PHP generated IMG tag on the page.

Comment: You're not attaching your image to your AJAX call, or if you are you've elected not to post it. Simply having a file-type input in your HTML isn't enough.

Comment: In the original submit page, I don't use a call to post the image. It's located inside the form.

From my understanding of the jQuery AJAX call, that's what the $_FILES["productImage"] is supposed to pull from the form. So if I'm submitting and haven't uploaded an image, it should return NULL, the second if statement, but isn't running that query.

Comment: That being said, if I do have to pass the newly uploaded image through the options, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: You're using `if (file_exists($upload))` - Read the manual on the function http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php - You're trying to check if a temp file exists (which shouldn't be the case; check if the uploaded file's name does exist), and on top of that, there's no file/folder pointer for it to look for. So, that'll fail right there. Then there's your HTML form, which isn't posted but not sure whether you have a valid enctype in it, and if it's using POST as the method. So, very hard to say at this point.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: This is my form tag:

<form method="POST" action="php/editInv.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="editInv">

I have trieid is_uploaded_file as well with the same lack of results. 

All add the HTML form to the code up top so you can look at it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- The error that came back is undefined index for the image upload, $productImage where I set the $upload variable.

Comment: If you're trying to check if a file exists already and you want to avoid duplicate names in upload, then `file_exists()` against a temp file won't work. You need to check using `$_FILES["productImage"]["name"]` not `$_FILES["productImage"]["tmp_name"]` and also adding a parameter for a folder to check into.

Comment: Ok, I might have explained that wrong. At this point, I'm not checking anything on the back end. I just need the php to send one query if the user didn't choose to upload a new photo, and another if the user wants to use the image entry that is already in the database.

I already have the validation in the entry page, as I use the php to rename my files to the product name before saving them perm. to the server. Image names cannot be the same because product names cannot be the same. This particular aspect is not checking for duplication.

Comment: `if(!empty($_FILES['productImage']['name'])) { do something } else{ ... }` instead of `if(file_exists($upload))`

Comment: Ok, that got rid of the error, but it still isn't running the query inside the else statement

Comment: I spotted something else: `if(isset($_POST["submit"]))` you don't have a button type submit with a name attribute called "submit", so everything inside there will fail. Might not fix the rest of it, but you still need to use `if/else` and nothing in between. You will need to reduce the amount of conditional statements, or use a different and more simpler approach. First check if a file has been chosen; if so, execute something. If one is not chosen, then execute something else. You can then add other things inside there. Once you've done/accomplished that, the rest is gravy.

Comment: This `if (!file_exists($upload)) {
  $sql=` should be replaced by an `else{ $sql... }` from what I said previously.

Comment: I'll update my PHP at the top so you can see what I have right now.

Comment: Ok, so I did an Echo, and it's entering the proper statements, but not running the SQL, do I need to put my $con inside the if statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it was actually being caused by two different issues, one in the PHP and one in the order in which the variables were called in the JavaScript. I had to call everything except for the generated image using jQuery at the top of the page as global variables, then put the jQuery AJAX at the bottom of the page with the form action call.

Apparently, using the jQuery to call the values of the fields at the bottom of the page caused them to send the information that the page populated with from the back end, while placing them at the top of the page causes them to relay the changed input data to the AJAX call.

Any explinations why this worked this way?

```
  <script>
      var productName = $('#productName').val();
      var productDesc = $('#productDesc').val();
      var inventory = $('#inventory').val();
      var price = $('#price').val();
      var gender = $('#gender').val();
      var prodId = $('#prodId').val();
  </script>
```

//All your HTML Content

```
<script>
  var options = {
  beforeSubmit: function() {
     // pre submit callback
     $("#progress").show();
     $("#percent").html("0%");
  },
  data: {
     productName : productName,
     productDesc : productDesc,
     inventory : inventory,
     price : price,
     gender : gender,
     image : $('#prevImage').attr('src'),
     prodId : prodId
  },
  uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
     //during submission
     $("#bar").width(percentComplete+'%');
     $("#percent").html(percentComplete+'%');
  },
  success: function(msg) {
     //post submit call back
     $(".bar").css("width","100%");
     $(".percent").html('100%');
     $("#response").html(response.responseText);
  },
  complete: function(response) {
     if(response.responseText=="Invalid File"){
     } else {
        $("#response").html(response.responseText);
        //$("#addNew")[0].reset();
        //$("#prevImage").attr('src','').hide();
        $(".bar").css("width","0%");
        $(".percent").html('0%');
     }

  },
  error: function(response) {
     alert(response.responseText);
  }

};


$("#editInv").ajaxForm(options);
  </script>
```

PHP if statement statement essentially looks like this:

```
if (!empty($_FILES["productImage"]["name"])) {
} else
//If a file has not been uploaded
if (empty($_FILES["productImage"]["name"])) {
}
```

Thank you @fred-ii- for the error catcher.

Answer (score 0):

The path you need to check is `$targetFileUpload` not `$upload`.

Once uploaded check:

```
if (!file_exists($targetFileUpload)){...}
```

Comment: Ok, I might have explained that wrong. At this point, I'm not checking anything on the back end. I just need the php to send one query if the user didn't choose to upload a new photo, and another if the user wants to use the image entry that is already in the database. I already have the validation in the entry page, as I use the php to rename my files to the product name before saving them perm. to the server. 

Thank you for your response though.

Comment: what do you mean by `if the user didn't choose to upload a new photo,` @MarvinWordWeaverParsons

Comment: Ok, this is an edit page, that automatically populates data from a previous entry in the database based on a productId SELECT. so the page automatically populates with the product name, price, inventory, description, gender, and URL to the current image for that entry. This gives the user the ability to choose a different image, or keep the one they currently have and just update the information. 

So there should already be an image present on the page (#prevImage). If the user wants to use this image for the UPDATE, then there shouldn't be an entry in $_FILES, sending a NULL.